# nginx equivalent of apache server-status?

Tags: nginx

The /nginx_status handler is billed as the equivalent of apache's /server-status however it looks to only display a summary of webserver activity:

```
Active connections: 109 
server accepts handled requests
4113871 4113871 8730647 
Reading: 0 Writing: 49 Waiting: 59
```

What I'm looking for is additional output, similar to Apache's /server-status which also lists all the inbound connections and which virtualhost they are connecting to. I can't seem any way to find this for nginx.

Alternatively, what's a quick and dirty way to figure out which virtualhost in a shared environment is the one taking an abnormal amount of traffic/activity/resources (short of trying to look at all the individual access logs)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I assume that by "the /nginx_status handler" you mean [ngx_http_stub_status_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_stub_status_module.html)? This is not clear from your question. It seems that nginx plus has this feature (https://www.nginx.com/products/live-activity-monitoring/).

Comment: Hello, thank you. Yes that is the one. I was hoping there was a way to see this without upgrading to nginx plus but maybe it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

So the way to get this with nginx is to upgrade to nginx plus.

However, you can also install [httpry](https://github.com/jbittel/httpry) which can give me a pretty good indication of what I'm after.

The really low-rent way to go is even:

```
 tcpdump -i eth0 port 80 -A|grep Host:
```

if the reason you want to look at this is to figure out which one of your sites is getting hit hard these will do it.